# How to scroll up with 'B' key in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard, scrolling

I am used to scrolling up and down with the space bar and the 'B' key in more/less on Unix, to an extent that it is "programmed in my muscle memory".

While Firefox supports scrolling down with the space bar, it does not scroll up with the 'B' key.

Any idea for getting the 'B' key working this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a extension called [Keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) that will allow you to define custom shortcut commands.

1. Install it.
2. Open the extension (`Ctrl + Shift + F12` on Windows).
3. Click `Add a new key`.
4. Leave the default name.
5. Replace `/* CODE */` by `goDoCommand("cmd_scrollPageUp");`.
6. Click `OK`.
7. Replace `<Disabled>` by `B`.
8. Click `Apply`.

Pressing `B` now should have the desired effect.

Comment: Works for me. Note that this requires disabling Firefox "find as you type" feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to scroll up.

If you specifically want to use <kbd>B</kbd> to scroll up, you'll have to install an addon called [Mouseless Browsing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mouseless-browsing/). After downloading and installing the addon, restart Firefox, and click on the "Mouseless Browsing" icon, found in the Firefox status bar. Click on the "Keys" tab. Select "Scroll Up" from the menu. Type <kbd>B</kbd> into the "Shortcut" box, then click "Assign."

Comment: Thanks für the suggestion. However I want 'b'.

Comment: Please see my edit.